# How to constrain a sum of parameters to one value with Python lmfit?

Tags: python, constraints, curve-fitting, lmfit, levenberg-marquardt

I'm using python `lmfit` to minimise the residuals of a fit function with three variables; `A`, `P` and `S`. I've provided a simplified version here:

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters
import numpy as np

# define model
def my_model(params, x):
    A = params['A']
    P = params['P']
    S = params['S']
    return A*x**2 + B*x + C


# define objective function
def residual(params, x, y, errs):
    return (y - my_model(params, x)) / errs


# import data
data = np.loadtxt('data/test.csv')
xs, ys, yerrs = data[0], data[1], data[2]


# initialise parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('A', value=0.8,  vary=True,  min=0,  max=1)
params.add('P', value=0.15, vary=True,  min=0,  max=1)
params.add('S', value=0.05, vary=True,  min=0,  max=1)


# minimise objective function to find optimal parameters
lsq = minimize(my_model, params, args=(xs, ys, yerrs))
```

My question is, how can I constrain my parameters such that they satisfy `A + P + S = 1`, while still allowing them all to freely vary to best fit the data? Perhaps something along the lines of:
`lsq = minimize(my_model, params, args=(xs, ys, yerrs), constraints=['A+P+S=1'])`

I have tried using an additional parameter `params.add('epsilon', expr='1 - A - P - S', min=0, max=0.0001)` but this does not constrain the data properly and condition is not satisfied - I'm not sure why. Also setting `vary=False` for this parameter seems to be ignored, and it simply varies such that the condition is satisfied with a negative value for `epsilon`, allowing `A + P + S` to be greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to recognize is that if you want to constrain your Parameters such that A + P + S = 1, then they are not actually all freely varying. You have two free variables and one Parameter that is constrained by those two variables.  I think what you want to do is

```
params = Parameters()
params.add('A', value=0.8,  vary=True,  min=0,  max=1)
params.add('P', value=0.15, vary=True,  min=0,  max=1)
params.add('S', expr='1-A-P',  min=0,  max=1)
```

That will almost guarantee that the sum is 1 -- I say almost because the added bounds on all Parameters may lead to a marginal violation of the constraint.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any standard procedure to follow for choosing which variable not to freely vary? What comes to mind is perhaps the one which the objective function is most sensitive to?

Comment: Hm, I don't know of a standard approach for that.  But if one of the variables has a particular spiky or erratic effect on the residual, it should be the one to not allow to vary freely.   That is, the Jacobian (d_Residual / d_Variable) being smooth and fairly parabolic does make fitting somewhat easier, so if it obvious that one has a non-smooth Jacobian, it would be better to have that be the constraint.  But, I would also admit that I very rarely think about that, and would just constrain the one that is most clearly or easily expressed as a constraint.